# Inserting subscription doesn't effect subscriber count - Youtube Data API V3

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube Data API's Subscription/insert doesn't change subscriber count. Properly worked in developers.google document page, 'Try this method'.

I have 2 youtube channels. I want to get first one to be subscribed by second. But i failed to do so.

I try to subscribe to [the channel named Catty](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4DC_ogWXR3veQODauNR6Ig) via youtube api. Used [subscriptions/insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) in Python:

```
def subscribe(self, channelId):
    return self.youtube.subscriptions().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "resourceId": {
                    "channelId": channelId
                }
            }
        }).execute()
```

Response from youtube:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#subscription",
    "etag": "gSyz_HE2Dk66ToVdaf0jAVZ_Gp0",
    "id": "w-TZ_LJtOGgBvG8K7sdq0VSqLvzWIQuPwOWwrgKrXkg",
    "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2023-05-04T12:53:57.567632Z",
        "title": "Catty",
        "description": "hello it is my channel",
        "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "channelId": "UC4DC_ogWXR3veQODauNR6Ig"
        },
        "channelId": "UC0BDRmi8nxMrNc9uwAK2jpA",
        "thumbnails": {
            "default": {
                "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/GE8QkE0YN0gwruYUIJy9xWcRQHaAU0bkypSCPEh1BXv8wJZmH-BMnoL0ca15A_wlSlGfcGgR=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/GE8QkE0YN0gwruYUIJy9xWcRQHaAU0bkypSCPEh1BXv8wJZmH-BMnoL0ca15A_wlSlGfcGgR=s240-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
            },
            "high": {
                "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/GE8QkE0YN0gwruYUIJy9xWcRQHaAU0bkypSCPEh1BXv8wJZmH-BMnoL0ca15A_wlSlGfcGgR=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like insertion succeeded but the channel's subscriber count doesn't increase. When i log into the subscriber channel, i can see the other channel in the subscriptions list. If i try to unsubscribe manually from the channel's page, it works but subscriber count doesn't decrease as expected.

I tried developers.google's '[try this method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22snippet%22%3A%7B%22resourceId%22%3A%7B%22channelId%22%3A%22UC4DC_ogWXR3veQODauNR6Ig%22%7D%7D%7D%7D)' and it changed subscriber count of the channel unlike my code. I could neither figure it out nor find anybody who encountered this situation. I need your help.

Comment: Probably is because the subscription is controlled by YouTube and they need to check if is not a bot - i.e. if it is a valid subscription. You might have more chances of getting answers by searching or submitting a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&pli=1&template=874803) - maybe the YouTube Data API has some sort of bug.